# Cuál es el error en mi código

Tags: sintaxis

Soy un programador novato y he tratado de buscar cuál es el error en mi código, según parece es sintaxis, sin embargo a mí me parece que está bien:

while i<=customers:

```
print("Tipo Precio\n A 5.000\n B 10.000\n C 20.000\n")
productType = str(input("Indica el tipo de producto seleccionado:"))
quantity = int(input("Indique la cantidad de productos que serán comprados:")
if productType == "A":
    productoA.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoA.printCost()
    i += 1
elif productType == "B":
    productoB.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoB.printCost()
    i += 1
elif productType == "C":
    productoC.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoC.printCost()
    i += 1
else:
    print("¡No existe el tipo de producto indicado!")
```

el error aparece en la linea if productType == "A": , imagino que las otras dos están igual

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error

Comment: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 29) pylint(syntax-error) [29,27]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola el error estaba en que te faltaba un paréntesis en la linea 3

```
print("Tipo Precio\n A 5.000\n B 10.000\n C 20.000\n")
productType = str(input("Indica el tipo de producto seleccionado:"))
quantity = int(input("Indique la cantidad de productos que serán comprados:"))
if productType == "A":
    productoA.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoA.printCost()
    i += 1
elif productType == "B":
    productoB.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoB.printCost()
    i += 1
elif productType == "C":
    productoC.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoC.printCost()
    i += 1
else:
    print("¡No existe el tipo de producto indicado!")
```

saludos

Answer (score 0):

creo que te falta un parentesis en la linea #3

```
print("Tipo Precio\n A 5.000\n B 10.000\n C 20.000\n")
productType = str(input("Indica el tipo de producto seleccionado:"))
quantity = int(input("Indique la cantidad de productos que serán comprados:"))

if productType == "A":
    productoA.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoA.printCost()
    i += 1
elif productType == "B":
    productoB.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoB.printCost()
    i += 1
elif productType == "C":
    productoC.priceCalculation(quantity)
    productoC.printCost()
    i += 1
else:
    print("¡No existe el tipo de producto indicado!")
```

podría ayudarte mucho instalar un editor de texto con colores para comenzar